# C# Generic Sql method without going into spaghetti code.

Tags: c#, oop, generics, inheritance

I am fairly new to C# and I am trying to semi convert my PHP framework into C#.

One of the things I wanted to do is to create a "generic" Sql object. for this purpose I created the following class:

```
    class SqlTemplates
{
    public static const int READ_FROM_QUERY = 1; // Read query result.
    public static const int RFQ = 1;
    public static const int READ_INSERT_ID = 2; // Read id from insert.
    public static const int RII = 2;
    public static const int FORCE_MULTIDIMENSIONAL = 4; // Forces a return of a multidimensional array.
    public static const int FM = 4;
    public static const int RFQ_FM = 5; // Read from query and force multidimensional.

    public OracleProvider database { get; set; }
    public OdbcConnection oracleConnection;

    public SqlTemplates(OracleProvider database)
    {
        this.database = database;
    }

    public ArrayList template(String query, int option = 0)
    {
        ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
        this.oracleConnection = database.getDb();
        this.oracleConnection.Open();
        OdbcDataReader cdr = null;
        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(query, this.oracleConnection);
        try
        {
            oracleConnection.Open();
            switch (option)
            {
                case RFQ:
                    cdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    break;
                case RII:
                    cdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    break;
                case FM:
                    cdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    break;
                case RFQ_FM:
                    cdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    break;
                default:
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    break;
            }

            if (option != 0)
            {
                while (cdr.Read())
                {
                    result.Add(cdr.NextResult());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public ArrayList prepared(String query, Dictionary<String, String> values, int option = 0)
    {
        ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
        this.oracleConnection = database.getDb();
        oracleConnection.Open();
        OdbcCommand cmd = oracleConnection.CreateCommand();

        OdbcDataReader cdr = null;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> entry in values)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(entry.Key, entry.Value);
        }

        if (option != 0)
        {
            cdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (cdr.Read())
            {
                result.Add(cdr.NextResult());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Now in one of my other questions (which was not related to this) it was pointed out to me that ArrayList is sort of deprecated with .NET > 2.0.

My problem is that if i use `List<T>` then I would have to know what goes into the object (which I don't because it vary depending on the system).

Now my question is how would I solve this issue?

The only idea i can think of is creating an Interface that all objects and result gained from Sql implements. However I am not sure I like this approach because it could get messy.

So my question is how can I avoid spaghetti code while still maintaining a `generic` class?

Comment: What for? I mean, there is this thing called "LINQ" and you are just there moving a second grade PHP framework instead of relying on technology that is standard in .NET and not even envisioned in PHP.

Comment: I think you should have a look at the different data access technologies in .NET before trying to implement something from scratch.

Comment: What does LINQ do? and how does it make my job easier?

Comment: There are already multiple ways to do this. You can use an ORM like NHibernate or Entity Framework, combined with LINQ, or even the (slightly obsolete) Linq-To-SQL. Compared to what you are trying to do it's much simpler. Or you can use a Micro-ORM like Dapper.NET or Massive to do mapping in a very simple way, paying a bit of performance due to reflection. Even plain-old ADO.NET is probably cleaner than what you have now

Comment: I agree with the other comments on LINQ and the available frameworks, but to answer your question about the `List`, I think you could just use `List<Object>` to get as generic as possible. But I've never done that myself. Anybody else know if that would work?

Comment: You might want to have a look to Open Source Micro ORMs like Massive, Petapoco, Dapper and get inspired by their code. Have some self training with OO, interfaces, generics, then learn tools like ADO.NET, LINQ to objects. It's perfectly OK to learn something by reinventing the wheel and figure yourself.

Comment: Additionally, using int constants instead of an Enum is considered very bad practice. So is opening a connection but not closing it after use. ADO.NET uses connection pooling to reuse connections instead of opening new ones. Equally bad, not having a `using()` clause to close the connection even if an error occurs